# Using "RootDirectory" in launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm writing a potentially destructive script to temporarily archive and then eventually delete files no longer needed on a client's FTP system running Mac OS X Server 10.7.

To expand, I'm switching through the set of FTP home directories, performing a find for any files older than 30 days, then moving those files into an "Archived" directory where if they remain for an additional 30 days, they will be deleted.

I intend to set this script to run every 30 days automatically using launchd as it is the preferred method for Mac OS X.

And it also has (or claims to have) the ability to chroot jobs when it starts them with a key in the plist called "RootDirectory", but I CANNOT get to to work.

Apple's own documentation on the subject seems very lean and I've been unable to find a single example of a launchd plist that actually uses the RootDirectory key.

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Include the `RootDirectory` key in your daemon’s configuration property list with Directory as string. Use `StartCalendarInterval` with 30 days

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.dts.SampleD</string>
        <key>RootDirectory</key>
        <string>path</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/tmp/SampleD</string>
        </array>
        <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Sockets</key>
        <dict>
            <key>MyListenerSocket</key>
            <dict>
                <key>SockServiceName</key>
                <string>12345</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```